# Bottomsheet not allowing the container to show its properties in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to have a draggable bottom sheet for which I have written the code. But the problem is bottom sheet is shown properly but the body has a container and that is not shown. Can somebody help me with the same. If I run the code without bottomsheet it runs properly. I am unable to figure out where is the problem

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF1E2129),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            top: 150,
            child: Container(
              height: height * .4,
              width: double.maxFinite,
              color: const Color(0xFF1E2129),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(width: 24),
                  Container(
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      /* image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('images/p1.png'),
                      ),*/
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: const Color(0xFF3B414F), width: 1.0),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                    ),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.message,
                      color: Color(0xFFBBFFF3),
                      size: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 12,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Somnio Software',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomSheet: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
          return ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 32),
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'DIRECT MESSAGES',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 10),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
          /*Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    itemCount: 20,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item $index'),
                        )),
                      );
                    }),
              );*/
        },
        initialChildSize: .6,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]DraggableScrollableSheet is always display in bottom no need to attached with bottom sheet,
Just drag into stack (as mentioned below)

```
Stack(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
    children: [
      Positioned.fill(
        top: 150,
        child: Container(
          height: height * .4,
          width: double.maxFinite,
          color: const Color(0xFF1E2129),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(width: 24),
              Container(
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  /* image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('images/p1.png'),
                  ),*/
                  color: Color(0xFF1E2129),
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: const Color(0xFF3B414F), width: 1.0),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.message,
                  color: Color(0xFFBBFFF3),
                  size: 15,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              const Text(
                'Somnio Software',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      DraggableScrollableSheet(
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {

          return ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 32),
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'DIRECT MESSAGES',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 10),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
          /*Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item $index'),
                    )),
                  );
                }),
          );*/
        },
        initialChildSize: .6,
      )
    ],
  ),
```

See the Output...

Answer (score 0):

you should try a function called bottom Model sheet and make it use in your project..

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

you can find it on flutter api